# 2 basic CSS questions

Tags: html, css

I am coding a practice site using Microsoft Expression Web 4 but I am having a lot of difficulty getting past the landing page. I have all code copied below the questions. The first problem is that I have a hover effect on the links in the nav menu that overlaps the nav bar and I want the text centered within the nav bar vertically. I have tried several how-tos on css-tricks.com and the browser display doesn't seem to respond to the edits I make I tried from there. [navbar issue and overflowing image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fV0t.png) I can manually adjust it so that if fits by figuring out pixels by trial and error but this seems clunky and non-responsive. Is there a better way?

The second question is the image I have for the header section is not fitting the screen properly. It overflows on the right side. It didn't do this before, but now it is and I haven't changed any of the code in the #header img {} section, so I am not sure what happened. I'm pretty much a beginner at this so thanks for any help.

HTML

```
<head>

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"/>   

<div id="header">

    <div class="nav">
        <div id="menu">
            <a href="#0">Home</a>
            <a href="#0">Travel</a>
            <a href="#0">Safari</a>
            <a href="#0">Live</a>
            <a href="#0">Search</a>
        </div>


    </div>  


    <img alt="drakensburg" src="images/drakensburg.jpg" />

    <h1>Visit Africa</h1>   


</div>

</head>
```

CSS

```
 #header {
    position:relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 600px;
    overflow:hidden;
    right: .5em;
    bottom: 1em;

}

#header .nav {
    display:inline-block;
    height:40px;
    width:100%;
    background-color:#a41d0e;
    overflow:visible;
    z-index: 10;
}

.nav #menu a{
    display: inline;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.nav #menu a:hover {
    background-color:#7f170b;
}
```

Comment: If you give your question a more descriptive title, more people will click through and look at it.

Comment: where do you want to position your image?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the HTML shown is in the <head> which is invalid and may be the cause of his issues. Also, there are two questions which may not be directly related, possibly making this too broad.

Comment: The typo is not the cause of his issues.

Comment: and it's @baao who added it.

Comment: What did i add @Supersharp

Comment: a </head> at the wrong place (it's what I see in the history, maybe it's a bug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS properties `display: flex` and `align-items: center` to center vetically items in a row.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #a41d0e;
}
nav a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
nav a:hover {
  background-color: #7f170b;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <body>
  <header>
    
    <nav id="menu">
      <a href="#0">Home</a>
      <a href="#0">Travel</a>
      <a href="#0">Safari</a>
      <a href="#0">Live</a>
      <a href="#0">Search</a>
    </nav>

    <img alt="drakensburg" src="images/drakensburg.jpg" />
    
    <h1>Visit Africa</h1>
    
  </header>
 <body>
<html>
```

Comment: Did not know about the automatic margin on the body. Thanks! That fixed my weird positioning issues.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing except the link tag should be between `<head></head>` in the exmple you gave! I assume that's a mistake.

```
#header {

        width: 100vw;
        height: 600px; 
        overflow:hidden; 
    }
```

technically you don't need any styles for your header. See css for img below. If you want to your header to be 600px, and have your image fill it, you should set your image as a background image in css

```
 background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
```

Alternatively, you could :

```
 /*style your image like so. It won't ever be wider than its immediate parent container*/
      img{

       max-width: 100%; 
       height auto;
      }
```

Here is the rest of your css, commented.

```
  #header .nav {

      /* no need for any display property here as it is block by default and takes up 100% of the width you probably don't need it to be inline-block either if it'll take up 100% of the width */

        height:40px;
        background-color:#a41d0e;
/*z-index is only useful for positioned elements (relative, absolute or fixed) so either give position: something to your navbar or ditch the z-index !*/

    }
```

As far as the links go you don't need to give them a top and bottom padding, just give them a line-height that is equal to the height of the container, that is 40px. That way the links will be vertically centered, with the same height as their container, and you will still be able to give them the width of your choice with left and right padding.

```
        .nav #menu a{
            /*don't need display: inline as it is negated by the float anyway.
position relative alone like this doesn't serve any purpose. vertical-align middle only works for display: inline-block or table/(s)*/
            float:left;
            line-height: 40px;
            padding: 0 1em 0 1em;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
```

Very useful link where you'll find a whole lot of very useful explanations on all things CSS : http://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/

Hope any of this helps!

Comment: Thanks! The navbar is perfect now. The image still overflows to the right, however. I made all changes as you suggested and I'm still not sure why it started doing this in the first place. It was fine when I started. Here's my code for the img right now. It doesn't seem to be linked to the html img as I'ved tried several units and sizes, but nothing changes. 

#header img {
 max-width:100%;
 heght: auto;}

I would do the background image method, but it seems like MEW4 can't find the file when I link it in CSS. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        nav {
            display: flex;
            background-color: #a41d0e;
        }
        nav a {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            padding: 15px 35px;
            text-decoration: none;
            color: white;
        }
        nav a:hover {
            background-color: #7f170b;
        }
        .outer {
            width: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .inner {
            display: inline-block;
            position: relative;
            right: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        img {
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            top:0;
            right: 0
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav id="menu">
            <a href="#0">Home</a>
            <a href="#0">Travel</a>
            <a href="#0">Safari</a>
            <a href="#0">Live</a>
            <a href="#0">Search</a>
        </nav> 
        <div class="outer">
            <div class="inner">
                <img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zvTnqSbUAk8/Tm49IrDAVCI/AAAAAAAACv8/05Ood5LcjkE/s1600/Ferrari-458-Italia-Nighthawk-6.jpg" alt="" />
                <h1>Visit Africa</h1> 
            </div>
        </div>      
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```